# Canvas sequence image

Tags: javascript

Having problem in JavaScript. My code should create a sequence images animation with a final new layer filled by a text.
I other words I would like to launch by clicking on a form button an animation that show at the end a text generated from a text-field.

```js
var canvas;
var context;
var photo;
var timer;
var count = 0;

function StartAnimation() {
  img = new Image();
  canvas = document.getElementById("Canvas1");
  context = canvas.getContext("2d");
  AnimateNow();
  img.src = 'roto-ball/image1.png';
}

function AnimateNow() {
  count++;
  img.src = 'roto-ball/image' + count + '.png';
  context.drawImage(img, 0, 0, 300, 300);

  timer = setTimeout(AnimateNow, 10);

  if (count == 30) {
    StopAnimation();
  }
}

function StopAnimation() {
  count = 0;
  clearTimeout(timer);
}

function ResetCanvas() {
  count = 0;
  context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
}
```

```html
<form>
  <label for="fname">First name:</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" value="John"><br>
  <label for="lname">Last name:</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname" value="Doe"><br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
<canvas id="Canvas1" width="300" height="300" style="border:5px solid green;">
    Canvas is not supported in your browser
</canvas>
<br />
<input type="button" onclick="StartAnimation()" value="Start Animation" />
<input type="button" onclick="StopAnimation()" value="Stop Animation" />
<input type="button" onclick="ResetCanvas()" value="Reset" />
```

Comment: What specifically is not working? Please read how to [ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @Xitiz Please read [When should code formatting be used for non-code text?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254990/). "form button" and "text-field" are not code. Also the language is spelled JavaScript.

Comment: @Xitiz If the word had been input, then formatting the word as code would have been appropriate. "form button" is simply a phrase indicating a button on a form. In this case, the OP is not using a `button` element, so using code formatting for button is not called for. And since it's simply part of the phrase "clicking on a form button", it doesn't need code formatting at all; it's not referring to code at all; just the action of clicking on a button. Just calm down with the code formatting; it gets in the way of reading, as the answers to the meta question posted indicate.

Comment: I'm sorry for my bad question... 
What I got now is a animation stat start when i press on "StartAnimation()" and this could be ok... But my question is how i can add a newone and last element over the  sequence when finish  animation as "text" ? (Es. <span>Hello World</span>).

Please to forgive my poor explanation and let me thank all of you !